# ''Required" function doesnt seem to work with return confirm

Tags: javascript, html

Why is my required not triggering when i submit data that is incomplete? here is my code below:

```
<form class="form-adminpage" method="post" action="admin.php">
                <input type="text" name="project_title" placeholder="Project Title" required /><br>
                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" required /><br>
                <input type="text" name="province" placeholder="Province" required /><br>
                <input type="text" name="cost" placeholder="Cost" required /><br>
                <input type="Submit" name="button" value="Enter" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to add the following data?');">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` will trigger first. If you want to show the HTML 5 validations first, you can add your alert in the `onsubmit` event of form

```
<form class="form-adminpage" method="post" action="admin.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to add the following data?');">
    <input type="text" name="project_title" placeholder="Project Title" required="true" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" required /><br>
    <input type="text" name="province" placeholder="Province" required /><br>
    <input type="text" name="cost" placeholder="Cost" required /><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="button" value="Enter" >
</form>
```